# Retrieving Samples From different multiple Folders and putting into the separate Directory

Tags: linux

I have hundreds of samples with *.zip extension in hundred of different folders. Now I want to make a loop to retrieve all of them into one directory.

Yours help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please be more detailed: how do you have the list of zip-files available? Do the content all have individual names or would one possibly run into files of the same name? Do you want to maintain the directory structure? Do you want each zip-file extracted into a directory by the name of the zip-file (without suffix)? Also show some example of your structure - where are the "hundreds of samples" and "different folders"? All in subdirectories of the same dir?

Comment: In addition, if you say you "_want to make a loop_" I assume you want to either write a shell-script of formulate a "one-liner" command to enter on the terminal. If so, please specify what shell you are running. Do you want to retrieve literally _all_ ZIP-Files below a certain directory, or only specific ones?

Answer (score 0):

Why a loop ?

```bsh
find . -name "*.zip" -exec mv -n {} dest_dir
```